# vpn connection error 800 on tplink router

Tags: vpn

One more "error 800" question

When I am connecting with mobile hotspot, the connection succeeds, but when from my home wifi - fails with error 800.

I did next things:

- disabled firewall,
- enabled static ip for my machine on the router (tplink tl-wr841n) and checked the ip is indeed given to my machine.
- enabled ports forwarding on the router for ports 1732,47,1701,50,500,51,4500  for my static ip (both L2TPand PPTP, though via the hotspot the connection succeeds with PPTP protocol)
- enabled PPTP, L2TP and IPSec passthrough
- **EDIT:** rebooted router and modem

the connection with hotspot goes flawlessly, so apparently the problem is not with the client configuration but something in the network...

What steps could be taken to troubleshoot the issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you rebooted your router? Thats the first thing you should do.

Comment: yes sure. several times. also the modem.

Answer (score 0):

Many modem/routers have a VPN passthrough facility that allows inbound VPN connections to pass through the device to the LAN to, say, an internal VPN server.

Your router provides such a facility - as seen on the following page: http://screenshots.portforward.com/routers/TP-Link/TL-WR841N/Basic_Security.htm

You should enable the VPN technology being used - i.e. if your VPN is PPTP then only enable the PPTP passthrough. IPSec then only enable IPSec etc.